# Malformed Url in case of woocommerce api through android

Tags: java, android, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, malformedurlexception

The "woocommerce api generate signature" url is

```
String getUrl = GET&http%3A%2F%2Fprojectrepo.net%2Fscoop%2Fwp-json%2Fwc%2Fv2%2Forders&oauth_consumer_key%3Dck_2f53925c....6407f09f67f5f118d01ed80e%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
```

When the url is passed through the below method,

```
URL url = new URL(getUrl);
```

"malformed url" error is shown.

And when the "GET&" is ommited from the url,this error is gone.But the "GET&" is needed for signature generation in woocommerce api.

What is the problem? If any doubt,please comment.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `GET&http://projectrepo.net` is not a valid url. A url should always begin with a protocol like `http`, `https`, `ftp` and so on. `http://projectrepo.net` is  a valid url.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Got your point.But the problem in not that.It is just that woo commerce api needs the url to be like this.So how to implement it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the API?

Comment: @KNeerajLal please check this http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http

Comment: Check this, https://gist.github.com/Aroniez/41dbc5942f70641b397e

Comment: @KNeerajLal Ok am checking and letting you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the "GET&" characters before the url is mandatory for generating signature.When the actual posting of data is done the "GET&" characters should be ommited.

Everyone thanks for your time.